# A box contains $30$ resistors probability problem

Tags: probability

> A box contains $30$ resistors. $15$ of the resistors have nominal values of $1.0~K\Omega$, $10$ have nominal values of $4.7~K\Omega$, and $5$ have nominal values of $10~K\Omega$. $3$ resistors are taken at random and connected in series. What is the probability that the $3$ resistor combination will have a nominal resistance of $19.4~K\Omega$?

I made (10/30)(9/30)(5/28)=.01847 but my text book say that the true result is .0554 and I can´t see how to proceed

Can someone help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: To get 19.4KOhm, you will need two 4.7K and one 10K resistor. There is no other possibility. So, your problem is basically about the probability of selecting two 4.7K and one 10K resistor.

Comment: I made (10/30)(9/30)(5/28)=.01847 but my text book say that the true result is .0554 and I can´t see how to proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant to write $$\frac{10}{30} \cdot \frac{9}{29} \cdot \frac{5}{28}$$ then you were determining the probability of selecting two $4.7~K\Omega$ resistors and a $10~K\Omega$ resistor *in that order*.  However, the order in which the resistors are selected does not matter.  The favorable selections of three of the thirty available resistors entail selecting two of the ten $4.7~K\Omega$ resistors and one of the five $10~K\Omega$ resistors, giving a probability of $$\frac{\dbinom{10}{2}\dbinom{5}{1}}{\dbinom{30}{3}}$$

**Note:**  We can make your approach work.  If we treat the two nominal $4.7~K\Omega$ resistors as indistinguishable, then there are three orders in which we can select two $4.7~K\Omega$ and one $10~K\Omega$ resistor, depending on whether the $10~K\Omega$ resistor is selected first, second, or third, giving the probability 
$$\frac{5}{30} \cdot \frac{10}{29} \cdot \frac{9}{28} + \frac{10}{30} \cdot \frac{5}{29} \cdot \frac{9}{28} + \frac{10}{30} \cdot \frac{9}{29} \cdot \frac{5}{28} = 3 \cdot \frac{10}{30} \cdot \frac{9}{29} \cdot \frac{5}{28}$$
As you can verify, 
$$3 \cdot \frac{10}{30} \cdot \frac{9}{29} \cdot \frac{5}{28} = \frac{\dbinom{10}{2}\dbinom{5}{1}}{\dbinom{30}{3}}$$

Comment: you're great! thank you! I take this curse a few years ago, and I forget some things! thanks again